# Sublime Text 2 - Perl Format String Syntax (Code Snippets)

Tags: code-snippets, sublimetext2

I'm using the following code snippet:

`Entity${0/(\w+)/\u\1/g}`

This ensures the first character is uppercase and the rest is lowercase. How would I also ensure that hypens (-) and special characters are removed?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by doing the following:

`Entity${0/(\w+)([-\s]*)/\u\1/g}`

At the moment, this only removes hypens (-). I'd like to remove all characters except alphanumeric characters.

If there's a cleaner way, I'd be more than welcome to accept your answer instead.